# HTC 10 DAC/amp specifications

Tags: amplifier, audio, dac, android

I'm going to be doing a final year project revolving around music production and DACs are pretty important. Not going to go into detail (unless this question requires it) what the project is but I will need to know the specifications of the DAC that the HTC 10 phone is using.

This isn't the one that Snapdragon put on the chip, I'm looking for the specs of their stand-alone DAC. They claim its "studio quality" so I would also like to know if this is true, when compared to those expensive external DACs most audiophiles or music producers purchase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTC state it is a 24 bit DAC - beyond that there is little way of knowing the specific part unless you take one apart (and even then it may not have a standard part number as OEMs often have ICs with special part numbers). http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones/htc-10-audio/

Comment: @PeterSmith aw that is a bit annoying. If I'm correct external DACs and the DAC in the phone wouldn't differ too much in terms of quality? Would be more the I/O that would differ given the HTC is a 24bit one and electronics can't vary that much